# Drawing polygon on the google earth engine App instead of a point

Tags: google-earth-engine

i'm a newbie on app development with GEE. I would to  have a polygon to draw on the map  instead of a point. 
Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
// Create a Google Maps Drawing Manager for drawing polygons.
drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
  drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
  drawingControl: false,
  polygonOptions: {
    fillColor: '#ff0000',
    strokeColor: '#ff0000'
  }
});
```

There's an official [demo of polygon drawing in GEE](https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/tree/master/demos/polygon-drawing)